# Facing issues with kakfa keys while building a SQL audit system using Kafka connect & Debezium

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, mysql-connector, confluent-schema-registry, debezium

I have a table “**books**” in database motor. This is my source and for source connection I created a topic “**mysql-books**”. So far all good I am able to see messages on Confluent Control Center. Now these messages I want to sink into another database called "**motor-audit**" so that in audit I am should see all the changes that happened to the table “**books**”. I have given the topic “**mysql-books**” in my sink curl for sink connector since changes are being published to this topic.

My source config -

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8083/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "name": "jdbc_source_mysql_001",
    "config": {
            "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://0.0.0.0:8081",
            "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://0.0.0.0:8081",
            "name": "jdbc_source_mysql_001",
            "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
            "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
            "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
            "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/motor",
            "connection.user": "yagnesh",
            "connection.password": "yagnesh123",
            "catalog.pattern": "motor",
            "mode": "bulk",
            "poll.interval.ms": "10000",
            "topic.prefix": "mysql-",
            "transforms":"createKey,extractInt",
            "transforms.createKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
            "transforms.createKey.fields":"id",
            "transforms.extractInt.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
            "transforms.extractInt.field":"id"
            }
    }
```

My Sink config -

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/jdbc_sink_mysql_001/config \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://0.0.0.0:8081",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
  "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://0.0.0.0:8081",
  "name": "jdbc_sink_mysql_001",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
  "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "topics":"mysql-books",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/motor",
  "connection.user": "yagnesh",
  "connection.password": "yagnesh123",
  "insert.mode": "insert",
  "auto.create": "true",
  "auto.evolve": "true"
}'
```

This is how messages on the topic look like -
[image]

The keys are seen in bytes but even if I use either AvroConverter or StringConverter for the key and keep it same in both source and sink still I face the same error.

The database table which is into play is created with this schema -

```
    CREATE TABLE `motor`.`books` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

With all this I am facing this error -

```
    io.confluent.rest.exceptions.RestNotFoundException: Subject 'mysql-books-key' not found.
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.exceptions.Errors.subjectNotFoundException(Errors.java:69)
```

**Edit**: I modified the URL in sink to have localhost and given stringconverter to key and kep avroconverter for value and now I am getting a new error which is -

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Exception chain:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: BLOB/TEXT column 'id' used in key specification without a key length
```

**Edit 2**:
As suggested by @Onecricketeer I am trying Debezium and using below config for MysqlConnector. I have already enabled bin_log in ***mysqld.cnf*** but upon launching getting errors like -

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Field does not exist: id
```

This is my debezium config -

```
 {
  "transforms.createKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
  "transforms.extractInt.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://0.0.0.0:8081",
  "transforms.extractInt.field": "id",
  "transforms.createKey.fields": "id",
  "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
  "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://0.0.0.0:8081",
  "name": "mysql-connector-deb-demo",
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.IntegerConverter",
  "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "transforms": [
    "createKey",
    "extractInt",
    "unwrap"
  ],
  "database.hostname": "localhost",
  "database.port": "3306",
  "database.user": "yagnesh",
  "database.password": "**********",
  "database.server.name": "mysql",
  "database.server.id": "1",
  "event.processing.failure.handling.mode": "ignore",
  "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
  "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.demo",
  "table.whitelist": [
    "motor.books"
  ],
  "table.include.list": [
    "motor.books"
  ],
  "include.schema.changes": "true"
}
```

Before using "unwrap" I was facing `mismatched input '-' expecting <EOF> SQL`
hence upon looking for this fixed this using "unwrap" following this question - [Fix for mismatched input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56676303/mismatched-input-from-expecting-eof-sql).
Let me know if this is actually needed or not.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is not a routable address. Are those what you're really using for the converters?. Also, if you're using anything other than the AvroConverter for the key, your error should be different

Comment: This set up is on local no docker no server included basically the guide on confluent platform said to put the address which is there in schema-registry properties. On the second point , the error is same be it avroconverter or stringconverter for key.

Comment: Note: if you really want to audit all events in a source table, you will want to use Debezium

Comment: That's not quite what I asked. You should be using `localhost:8081`, then, but still unclear how `mysql:3306` gets resolved locally

Comment: 3306 is the port on which mysql is running. Source is able to pick from mysql correctly.

Comment: My point is that one connector is using `localhost:3306` and the other is `mysql:3306`... Regardless, please show the output of `curl localhost:8081/subjects`

Comment: Here's the output of curl - curl localhost:8081/subjects ->
["mysql-books-key","mysql-books-value"]

Comment: Okay, so the key is there. Now, what happens when you fix the converter urls to not use 0.0.0.0?

Comment: Also worth pointing out that you've never stated you want data written to the `motor-audit` table in the config

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231746/discussion-between-thealchemist-and-onecricketeer).

Comment: Your ID is an int, so use `key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.IntegerConverter`

Comment: I modified the URL in sink to have localhost and given stringconverter to key and kep avroconverter for value and now I am getting a new error which is - Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Exception chain:java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: BLOB/TEXT column 'id' used in key specification without a key length. I fixed this by following this link - https://rmoff.net/2021/03/11/kafka-connect-sqlsyntaxerrorexception-blob/text-column-used-in-key-specification-without-a-key-length/ and facing primary key constraints but atleast its trying to create db.
Looks like some issues in my DB schema.

Comment: Well, again, your ID is an integer, so why are you trying to use StringConverter for it?

Comment: @OneCricketeer   I have edited my post to include Debezium kindly have a look.

Comment: I think you should create a brand new post since you're now asking about errors for both sink and source connectors... In any case, I've never really used Debezium much

Comment: Thanks yes I have created a new post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67398061/debezium-issues-while-building-a-mysql-db-audit-system